# Transferring Value through session in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I have 4 jsp forms name **Sample1.jsp,Sample2.jsp,Sample3.jsp,Sample4.jsp**
I want to transfer value from one page to another through Session 
and I used this method

**Sample1.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="sample2.jsp" method="post">
            <h1>Page1</h1>
            <input type="text" name="name">
            <input type="submit" value="Go">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Sample2.jsp**
Got the value name from Sample1.jsp and redirected to sample3.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>page2</h1>
        <%
            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            session.setAttribute("name",name);
            out.println(name);
            //response.sendRedirect("sample3.jsp");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("sample3.jsp").forward(request, response);
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Sample3.jsp**
*Got the value name from Sample2.jsp and not displaying the anchor tag hyperlink in Sample3.jsp and directly jump to Sample4.jsp*

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Page 3</h1>
        <%
            String lname = (String)session.getAttribute("name");
            out.println(lname); 
            //session.setAttribute("lname",lname);
        %>

        <a href="<%request.getRequestDispatcher("sample4.jsp").forward(request, response);%>" value=""><%out.println(lname);%> </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

*The Code directly jump to Sample4.jsp without allowing the user to click the hyperlink in anchor tags in Form Sample3.jsp. Wanted to stop the page and allow the user to Click and move forward.*

**Sample4.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>page 4</h1>
        <%String name =(String)session.getAttribute("name");
        out.println(name);%>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add this to sample3.jsp request.getRequestDispatcher("sample4.jsp").forward(request, response);

Comment: I appled request.getRequestDispatcher but it gets jumped to sample4.jsp without  showing or clicking the value of lname in anchor tags in Sample3.jsp.

Comment: I appled this but it gets jumped to sample4.jsp without showing or clicking the value of lname in anchor tags in Sample3.jsp. I also want sample3.jsp to show the output and when i click the hyperlink in anchor tag in sample3.jsp then it should go to sample4.jsp

Comment: I fixed your problem.

Comment: Yeah thanks it worked but, from the first page it directly jump to the last page (4th one) without stopping on the 3rd form. Is there any way to handle it.

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your `<a href` ..... tag in which you forward your request into `sample2.jsp` and in `sample3.jsp` page you again forward the request so ultimately, request the reached to `sample4.jsp`.
Read more about from here [RequestDispatcher](http://www.javatpoint.com/requestdispatcher-in-servlet).

The solution of this problem :

try this

**Web.xml :**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>sample1.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>


</web-app>
```

**Sample1.jsp**

```
<body>
    <form action="sample2.jsp" method="post">
        <h1>Page1</h1>
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit" value="Go">
    </form>
</body>
```

**Sample2.jsp**

```
<body>
    <h1>page2</h1>
    <%
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        session.setAttribute("name",name);
        //out.println(name);
        //response.sendRedirect("sample3.jsp");

    %>
    <a href="sample3.jsp"><%out.println(name);%></a>

</body>
```

**Sample3.jsp**

```
<body>
    <h1>Page 3</h1>
    <%
        String lname = (String)session.getAttribute("name");
        //out.println(lname+"\n"); 
        //session.setAttribute("lname",lname);
    %>

    <a href="sample4.jsp"><%out.println(lname);%></a> 
</body>
```

**Sample4.jsp**

```
<body>
    <h1>page 4</h1>
    <%String name =(String)session.getAttribute("name");
    out.println(name);%>

</body>
```

Comment: It didn't worked as the variable **name** on page 4 is getting null value. Till the page 3 its transfer the value, but can't pass it on the page 4. I think 'request.getRequestDispatcher("sample3.jsp").forward(request, response);' is the right option. But the problem is it did't stops on the page 3, as there is an anchor tag which providing href to the page 4. It should stop there for the user to click on that href  '<a href="<%request.getRequestDispatcher("sample4.jsp").forward(request, response);%>" value=""><%out.println(lname);%> </a>'  and move to page 4.

Comment: Did you add <a href="sample4.jsp"><%out.println(lname);%></a> on sample3.jsp? it's working fine in my system.

Comment: Still the same problem value of name did't transfer from page 2 to 3. I don't think so <a href="sample3.jsp"><%out.println(name);%></a> will transfer the value from one jsp page to another.....!!!

Comment: remember you're using sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a RequestDispatcher in your `<a>` tags. The session values will remain persistent even in the **Sample4.jsp**, so even a basic hyperlink to it will be fine to use the values present in the Session.

Also if you wish to check out when to use **forward()** and when to use **sendRedirect()** method check out this link: http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/09/sendredirect-forward-jsp-servlet.html

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, but by taking normal hyperlink on page 3 and then moving to page 4 then its showing NULL value in **name** variable

Comment: @Salik47 Well yes when you are using a **JSP** page , session object will be created implicitly, so to prevent creating a new session object whenever a particular page is called you can use `<%@ page session="false" %>` declaration to your page

Comment: <%@ page session="false" %> so declaring in page 4 its showing the error: String name =(String)session.getAttribute("name");
                                 ^
  symbol:   variable session
  location: class sample4_jsp
1 error

Comment: @Salik47 don't use `<%@ page session="false" %>` simple hyperlink will work fine, comment me what you have written which is producing **NULL** value

Comment: i used <a href="sample4.jsp"><%out.println(lname);%></a>  in page 3 and <%String name =(String)session.getAttribute("name");
    out.println(name);%>       in page 4   through this i m getting null in name variable in page 4